# C# ServiceStack.Redis SetAll with expire

Tags: c#, caching, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

First, a link to the library: [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis)

now, Im working on some generic cache mechanism which supports, for now, in 4 methods:

Put, Get, PutMany, GetMany

Problem is, whenever I want to insert numerous records, I dont have an option (visible to me) to add an expiration, unlike Put - where I can.

The code is pretty streight forward:

```
public void PutMany(ICollection<T> items)
{
    TimeSpan expiration = GetExpiration();
    DateTime expire = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(expiration);

    Dictionary<string, CachedItem<T>> dict = new Dictionary<string, CachedItem<T>>();
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        CachedItem<T> cacheItem = new CachedItem<T>(item, expire);

        if (!dict.ContainsKey(cacheItem.Id))
            dict.Add(cacheItem.Id, cacheItem);
    }

    // Store item in cache
    _client.SetAll(dict);
}
```

the model `CachedItem<T>` is mine, just imagine it as some sort of an object.

As you can see, I dont have an option of setting the expiration.
Is there a way (besides inserting them 1 by 1 using `_client.Set()`) to achieve this?

TIA.

**P.S**

I know I can store all records in a list or an hash, I dont want that all the records will have a single expiration date (wrong, and can cause very serious performance issues whenever they expire)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis does not have any command that will let you [set an expiry with a bulk insert](https://redis.io/commands/mset) nor does any of its [Expire commands](https://redis.io/commands/expire) allow you to apply the expiry to multiple keys.

To avoid an N+1 operation you'll need to [queue multiple SET commands in a Redis Transaction](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisTransactions) or [pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/RedisPipelineTests.cs), setting each entry individually with an expiry, e.g:

```
using (var trans = Redis.CreateTransaction())
{
    foreach (var entry in dict) 
    {
        trans.QueueCommand(r => r.SetValue(entry.Key, entry.Value, expireIn));
    }

    trans.Commit();
}
```

Where ServiceStack.Redis will still send the multiple SET operations in a [bulk Redis transaction](https://redis.io/topics/transactions).

Comment: as long as its 1 request, thats fine.

Comment: @MichaC ServiceStack.Redis batches all commands in a single network write so it doesn't have N+1 request latency. LUA would be more overhead.

Comment: @mythz Redis still has to do n+1, that's what I meant. Sure, network latency is one thing, but the Redis Server still has to run all those commands ^^. Don't see why LUA would be more overhead? It would be exactly one command/request which then runs the loop on the server.

Comment: @MichaC The slowest part about executing N+1 requests is the latency of a separate network write/read per request, this doesn't happen with Redis pipelining as explained. LUA still has to execute the same commands on the server but with the additional script processing overhead.

Comment: @mythz there is no script processing overhead if you pre-load the LUA script. In addition, you don't have to put a "transaction" around all the commands because LUA scripts already run atomic which can improve performance. But hey, that's just another flavor ^^

Comment: @MichaC what do you think Redis does faster, executing Redis commands natively or running them through a LUA interpreter to execute them through a scripting proxy object? Transactions are also atomic, but that's not where the latency comes from as it would be marginally faster executing them through a non-atomic pipelined request